# Sorting an array of objects by multiple properties with additional constraints

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by multiple properties, specifically due date and name:

```
const sortByName = (a, b) => {
    const lc = x => x.name.toLowerCase();
    return lc(a).localeCompare(lc(b));
}

const sortByDueDate = (a, b) => {
    const time = x => x.due.getTime();

    if (b.due === null)
        return -1;

    if (a.due === null)
        return 1;

    return time(a) - time(b);
}

const items = [
    {name: 'AItem', due: new Date(2021, 8, 26)},
    {name: 'WItem', due: null},
    {name: 'TItem', due: new Date(2021, 7, 26)},
    {name: 'CItem', due: new Date(2021, 7, 26)},
    {name: 'ZItem', due: null},
    {name: 'OItem', due: new Date(2021, 1, 11)},

];

console.log(items.sort((a,b) => sortByDueDate(a,b) || sortByName(a,b)));
```

What complicates things here is that sometimes due dates can be `null`. In that case, such items should be moved to the bottom of the sorted array. The two additional conditions in the `sortByDueDate` function does exactly that. However, this means that elements with `due === null` are no longer sorted by name:

```
[
  { name: 'OItem', due: 2021-02-10T23:00:00.000Z },
  { name: 'CItem', due: 2021-08-25T22:00:00.000Z },
  { name: 'TItem', due: 2021-08-25T22:00:00.000Z },
  { name: 'AItem', due: 2021-09-25T22:00:00.000Z },
  { name: 'ZItem', due: null },
  { name: 'WItem', due: null }
]
```

Is there a neat way to fix this, i.e. maintain correct sorting for all elements in the sorted array? I know that I can sort by one property first and then by another but that would mean going through the whole array twice and I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add one line in your code

```
if(a.due === null && b.due === null){
      return sortByName(a,b)
}

function sortItems(a, b) {
    const sortByName = (a, b) => {
        const lc = x => x.name.toLowerCase();
        return lc(a).localeCompare(lc(b));
    }

    const sortByDueDate = (a, b) => {
        const time = x => x.due.getTime();
        if(a.due === null && b.due === null){
            return sortByName(a,b)
        }
        if (b.due === null)
            return -1;
    
        if (a.due === null)
            return 1;
    
        return time(a) - time(b);
    }

    return sortByDueDate(a, b) || sortByName(a, b);
}

const items = [
    {name: 'AItem', due: new Date(2021, 8, 26)},
    {name: 'WItem', due: null},
    {name: 'TItem', due: new Date(2021, 7, 26)},
    {name: 'CItem', due: new Date(2021, 7, 26)},
    {name: 'ZItem', due: null},
    {name: 'AItem', due: null},
    {name: 'KItem', due: null},
    {name: 'OItem', due: new Date(2021, 1, 11)},

];

console.log(items.sort(sortItems));
```

Comment: I do not see any reason moving 'sortByName ' and 'sortByDueDate ' to be under 'sortItems' scope.  Doing that do not let the option to reuse those function:

Comment: I agree, I moved those out of sortItems scope. Thanks E1ad.

Comment: Thanks Viktor, nice and simple. Should have figured it out by myself.